# how to see remote branches with multiple origins

Tags: git

I have two origin in my git repository:

```
user@user:$ git remote -v
      origin1   https://github.com/Company_Name/repository_name1.git (fetch)
      origin1   https://github.com/Company_Name/repository_name1.git (push)
      origin2   https://github.com/Company_Name/repository_name2.git (fetch)
      origin2   https://github.com/Company_Name/repository_name2.git (push)
```

I can push and pull for both without any problem.

Now I want to see remote branches for origin2, and I can get it. My try:

```
user@user:$ git branch -a
```

but all the branches are from origin1

Comment: Did you fetch origin2 remote?

Comment: I've just tried git fetch, but adding remote name worked! thanks, if you create it as answer I will mark it as a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first fetch the `origin2` remote.

Once the fetch is done, the `git branch -a` command you mentioned should include the branches from that remote.

```
git fetch origin2
git branch -a
```

P.S. You may want to give a more descriptive name to your remote than `origin2`. This will decrease the risk of confusing remotes. maybe `upstream`, `mirror`, `backup`? Whatever makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion, in my real repository there are different names and they are descriptive